# How can I change the google gantt chart font?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, google-visualization

When I start the first [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oge1t3Lx/) from the [Google Gantt Chart Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart), I get a serif font.

How can I switch to sans-serif as Google does it on its page?

I discovered `gantt.labelStyle`, but that only sets the labels' style **but not the tooltip font when hovering over items**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to add this CSS

```
text {
  font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
```

This will style all `text` nodes with a sans-serif font.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oge1t3Lx/1/)